# Make a single form append many records to a table, one for each record in a query?

Tags: append, cycle

My first post on here, have been lurking for a while and picked up many tips.

I have a database for a football team, which stores players personal records, and financial records too.  The players parents (it is a youth team) have to pay fees to play.

I have one table with players details such as name, contact details, date joined, and another table with financial details:  money they have paid in, money they are due to pay.  This financial table can look messy but the reports I have created tidy it up, it is a simple income/outgoing table.

The users have to, on the 1st of each month, use the income/outgoing form once for every player and state that the player's monthly fee of £20 is due, considering the club has about 100 players this is time consuming.

I would like a form that is based on a query of all players (or I can adjust the query to filter it to certain groups to suit and duplicate for more forms), that the user can input a date and amount, and this appends a different record for every player in to the financial table.

I do not know how to create VBA, but I can copy/paste code if required.

Thanks for your help!

Mark.